# Access VBA Set Focus in Column

Tags: ms-access, vba, setfocus, subforms

good afternoon,

I have an access with a subform (**sub_frm_robo2**) that has a specific column (**CD_SENHA**).

In the **Form Load event** I put the code: (***Me.sub_frm_robo2.Form! SENHA.InputMask = "Password"***)

and I am trying to create a condition that at the moment this Column
(**CD_SENHA**) receives focus (***Me.sub_frm_robo2.Form!SENHA.SetFocus***),

the data mask be removed (**Me.sub_frm_robo2.Form!SENHA.InputMask = ""**)

and when the focus changes to the next column return the data mask to the initial format (**Me.sub_frm_robo2.Form! PASSWORD = "Password"**)

Below some images to better exemplify

***Before Focus***
[image]

***With Focus***
[image]

***After Focus***
[image]

I think the code would look something like this

```
Do While Me.sub_frm_robo2.SetFocus = True
If Me.sub_frm_robo2.Form!SENHA.SetFocus Then
    Me.sub_frm_robo2.Form!SENHA.InputMask = ""
End If
Next
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did not have any help here but I managed to resolve after a few attempts and errors, just to code a code in the event of each column of the subformaluario to make it work. Good luck to everyone

```
Private Sub CNPJ_AF_GotFocus()

Me.Form!SENHA.InputMask = "Password"

End Sub

Private Sub SENHA_GotFocus()

Me.Form!SENHA.InputMask = ""

End Sub
```